# Gunicorn Setup with Django

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I've setup a gunicorn service like so

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=muiruri_samuel
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/chatsys
ExecStart=/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/chatsys/chatsys.sock chatsys.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

for a django app called `chatsys` with the virtualenv `djangoenv` in the shown folder.

This is on a Ubuntu server and after starting gunicorn and checking for a bug got this error back.

```
muiruri_samuel@train:~/webapp/chatsys$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-05-29 10:20:19 UTC; 2min 46s ago
 Main PID: 4862 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
May 29 10:20:19 train gunicorn[4862]:     self.stop()
May 29 10:20:19 train gunicorn[4862]:   File "/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
May 29 10:20:19 train gunicorn[4862]:     time.sleep(0.1)
May 29 10:20:19 train gunicorn[4862]:   File "/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_
May 29 10:20:19 train gunicorn[4862]:     self.reap_workers()
May 29 10:20:19 train gunicorn[4862]:   File "/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_wo
May 29 10:20:19 train gunicorn[4862]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
May 29 10:20:19 train gunicorn[4862]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
May 29 10:20:19 train systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 29 10:20:19 train systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn` for full stack trace.

Comment: found out I didn't install django channels